# Default parameters in constructor gives compile time errors

Tags: c++, constructor

I had learned that we can give default parameters to the constructor so that it initializes the values if not provided explicitly in code, but when I am trying to create an object of my class, it does not work. It does not take those default values if not provided, and it gives me an error which says:
`error: no matching function for call to ‘Person::Person(const char [6], int)`

```
Person::Person( string aName = "ANY", int age = 18 ) {
cout << "Constructor called!" << endl;
this->name = aName;
this->age = age;
}
```

Now when I call this in my main:

```
Person p( "Steve" );
```

It gives me the mentioned error and `age` does not get initialized by default to 18.

I am using eclipse for C/C++ IDE

Comment: Side note: Usually it is preferred to use a initializer list, for example: `Person(std::string aName = "ANY", int age = 18) : name(aName), age(age) {}`. See [Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default values for parameters should go into the declaration, not the definition:

```
class C {
    C(int a = 0);
}

C::C(int a)    // not C::C(int a = 0)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had initialized them in the wrong place, I had to do it in the class file(header file).

Answer (score 0):

As Evg already mentioned:

> default values for parameters should go into the declaration, not the
>   definition

Additionally I'd like to point out, that it's usually preferred to use a 'initializer list' in your constructor (Not to be confused with std::initializer_list), which looks something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string aName = "ANY", int age = 18) : name(aName), age(age)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor called!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    Person p1("Test123");
    std::cout << p1.name << ' ' << p1.age << std::endl;
    Person p2("Test456", 21);
    std::cout << p2.name << ' ' << p2.age << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This way your variables get initialized exactly once and it is much cleaner. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list. In your example `name` and `age` will be default initialized (even before your constructors body is executed) and assigned to, when you could also initialize it with the correct value immediately.

Comment: strictly speaking you are not answering OPs question

Comment: You're right, I will delete this answer and turn it into a comment.

Comment: why not just add a word or two, i mean it is almost an answer ;)